# Align to left side of contaner a element rotated -90deg

Tags: css, rotation, transform, css-transforms

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
h1 {
  width: 300px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hola</h1>
</div>
```

If you try this snippet, you will see that the `h1` is rotated and placed in the center of the div (makes sense, they have same width)

But how to align it to the left? (flexible container's width)

Comment: yes when `h1` is rotated its `initial_width` becomes `final_height` and `initial_height` becomes `final_width `

Comment: when you make `width` of `h1` to `height` than the `h1` will move left

Comment: Tested, works, But must it be another way, right? I need it to have reasonable background..

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: Yes, there is way but should it be left-top or left-bottom or left-middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out it will give a direction to your required solution..

```css
 div {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
 h1 {
   width: 70px;
   margin-left: -20px;
   float: left;
   transform: rotate(-90deg)
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hola</h1>
</div>
```

**Updated**

Or you can do in this way also

```css
 div {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
 h1 {
   position: absolute;
   left: -10px;
   top: 2px;
   transform: rotate(-90deg)
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hola</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can position the `h1` element absolutely with respect to the parent `div` and then use `transform-origin` property to specify the axis about which the rotation should happen.

In the below snippet, the element is positioned at the bottom of the parent and because the origin is set at left-bottom, the left-bottom of the element (`h1`) stays at its position during rotation.

Now because of the rotation, the element would go outside of the parent after rotation. To bring it back into position add `translateY(100%)` to the transform stack. A `text-align: right` is added to set the content at left-top. The `text-align` makes it look a bit more hackish than it actually is but otherwise it is difficult to position at `left-top`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
  border: 1px solid;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
div, h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hola</h1>
</div>
```

---

**Note to future visitors:** Unlike using static values for positioning, this solution using `translateY()` would be able to adapt itself automatically even if the length of the content increases or spans multiple lines like in the below snippet. Again, the only drawback would be that the text would be right aligned.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: right;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
  border: 1px solid;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
div,
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Halooo</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Some lengthy content which wraps around</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: the text is going out of div

Comment: @Amitsingh: Thanks for pointing it out. That was because I hadn't set `position: relative` on the parent. So, it was getting positioned with respect to the root.