# CSS use transform-origin to position a rotated element

Tags: css, css-transforms

I can't work out how to rotate an element so that it sits underneath another one. The image below should illustrate the intended result.

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far:

```css
.div1 {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div1 button {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: #999;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.originFromLeft .div2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 24px 24px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}
.div1.originFromRight {
  overflow: visible;
}
.originFromRight .div2 {
  padding-right: 12px;
  text-align: right;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <button>></button>
  <div class="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>

<div class="div1 originFromLeft">
  <button>></button>
  <div class="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>

<div class="div1 originFromRight">
  <button>></button>
  <div class="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

The second example basically does what I want but the text is orientated the wrong way.

The closest I can get is example 3 but I need to pull this back to the left. I've tried `translate` but I can't get it to work, I've tried a negative right `margin` of 100% which almost works but basically doesn't.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but the method detailed here should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602515/align-to-left-side-of-contaner-a-element-rotated-90deg/32602847#32602847 (basically position the `div` at bottom, align text to right and reverse rotate)

Comment: How long can the string be? Single line or multi-line? Does the container's dimensions change? (For the dimensions and text provided in question [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cqwxpL2z/) is a sample of what I meant.)

Comment: @Harry Sorry Harry, I missed the last example with the flexible string length on that link you sent. I've got it to work using those principles. I hadn't considered using positioning in addition to the transform.

Comment: No worries mate. Glad to know that you found it useful :)

Comment: If you wrap that fiddle up in an answer I will happily accept it rather than answer it myself. You should have the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method to achieve the expected output would be to do the following:

- Put the `button` within `div2` and position it at the right edge.
- Absolutely position the `div2` at the bottom of the parent container.
- Rotate the `div2` in counter clockwise direction (-90deg) with the transform origin at left bottom.
- After rotation, the `div2` would entirely go outside of the container and hence we need to add an extra `translateY(100%)` to the transform stack.
- The text is aligned to the right and an extra `padding-right` (greater than the width of the button) is added to keep the text away from the button.
- The button would also get rotated by -90 degree because it is a child of `div2` and to counter that (that is to make the button text get displayed properly), we need to apply counter rotation.

Now, in this approach the only drawback is that if the text length increases beyond what can be fit in a single line then it would wrap around to the next line (have a look at the second sample in snippet).

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 60px;
  line-height: 48px;
  background-color: #999;
  text-align: right;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">HELLO
    <button>></button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">HELLO WORLD!!!!!
    <button>></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have taken your second example and rotated the element the other way round.
And then fixed the position with an extra translateX

```css
.div1 {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div1 button {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: #999;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.originFromLeft .div2 {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  padding-left: 12px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1 originFromLeft">
  <button>></button>
  <div class="div2">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first sentence seems a bit broken pal. I think you meant *I have taken your second example*. The answer is nice by the way :)

Comment: Yes, my english should get better...   Thanks !