# Rotate div 90 degrees and position fixed in the upper left corner

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: preview]

I want to have a navigation that will be rotated 90 deegres and fixed to the upper left corner of the window.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="item">lasange</li>
            <li class="item">spaghetti</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    background: red;
}

.inner {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    background: green;
}
```

I can't get it to look like in the image above. The problem is with the rotation. The inner div is positioned and then rotated, and as a result ends up outside the outer div. No matter what I put as the origin of the transformation it doesn't work the way I want it to. I've tried positioning the inner div with `position: absolute` but with no luck. I don't know the height/width parameters of the menu list.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/949cjcnq/7/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Paul

Comment: This will not be directly in the left-hand corner, but what about [`transform-origin: 20 0`](https://jsfiddle.net/949cjcnq/8/)?

Comment: Can you not add `rotate -90deg` to `.outer` and remove it from `.inner`? This would solve your problem.

Comment: You can also apply a [translation like so](https://jsfiddle.net/949cjcnq/13/) to move the object the rotate it so it's in the corner of the page. Of course it requires that you know the width/height. Be it can be computed if you apply this using JavaScript afterwards.

Comment: I edited my answer, it should solve your issue now :)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890674/css-use-transform-origin-to-position-a-rotated-element/32891540#32891540)  should help you to a good extent.

Comment: if you're looking for a different way using `writing-mode`: https://jsfiddle.net/k1hpn49y/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I manage to position it the way you want, no matter how big your content is using `position: absolute;` for your *.inner*-div.

<strike>The only drawback is that your text is facing downwards and *not* upwards. Couldn't get around that issue with my CSS :S</strike>

If you `-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);` the child of `.inner` you can turn the text the right way up :)

```css
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  background: #AACAD7;
  white-space: nowrap;;
}
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; white-space: nowrap; }
ul li { padding: 5px 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <ul class="list rotate">
      <li class="item">lasange | spaghetti</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this rotation issue, the way you did it with the 2 separate rotations helped me a lot. Brilliant

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is move the rotation from the inner to the outer class. Your css should look like this:

```
.outer {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    top: 80px;
    background: red;
}

.inner {
    background: green;
}
```

To make the text appear side by side after rotation, using a table would work better than using a list:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <table class="list">
            <tr>
                <td class="item">lasange</td>
                <td class="item"> | </td>
                <td class="item">spaghetti</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/949cjcnq/12/

Comment: Check it now, it makes the text appear similar to the way it does in the image.

Comment: Not that, it's that the OP want's the element to be in the corner of the page. This rotates along the center of the object, so it will not be in the corner.

Comment: Like Spencer said, this will not achieve what I want since the rotation is not in the corner.

Answer (score 1):

Despite what you chose for the angle or rotation unfortunately you cannot do this without knowing the width of your item, as such I don't think it can be done in pure CSS/CSS3 without an expanded framework. As such to solve this you will need to use some JavaScript and get the computed width of the element and change the transformation appropriately:

```
var inner = document.querySelectorAll('.inner')[0];
var width = inner.offsetWidth;
inner.style.transform = "translateY("+width+"px) rotate(-90deg)";
```

Keep `transform-origin: 0 0` as it will have the top of the element to the edge of the screen. Then we simply need to translate in the Y direction by the width, this will place the element in the left corner:

[**Fiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/949cjcnq/16/)

Answer (score 0):

In the below snippet you will see that I removed the `outer` and `inner` html and just rotated the entire UL -90deg. The result is your example image. Further proper styling is up to you  ;-)

See snippet for comments:

```css
/* {outline: 1px dotted red } /* for debugging */

ul, li { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0 }

ul { height: 1; /* 1 x line-height */
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 6px;

    /* would be regular without transform */
    top: 20px; left: 20px;

    /* but transform-origin now pivots around
    top-right so UL element gets moved right.
    So left position needs correction:
    left = -1 x (total width of LI's + line-height + UL margin-LR + UL padding-LR) + wanted-left-margin */
    top: 20px; left: -134px; /* (optically estimated) */  
}

li {
    display: inline; /* result is horizontal menu */
}

.list {
    transform: rotate(-90deg); /* removed -webkit-*/
    transform-origin: top right;
    background: #acc9d7;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">lasange | </li>
    <li class="item">spaghetti</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a cleaner solution. One that will work without setting a specific numeric value like `left: -134px`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a translateX(-100%) to  your transform, that will set it where you want

```css
.outer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    background: red;
}

.inner {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    background: green;
}

.list {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="item">lasange</li>
            <li class="item">spaghetti</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```